# Why inputs and text fields look different on desktop and mobile (IOS/Android)

Tags: mobile, input-fields, input, web

I would like to hear from you why the view on mobile and web looks differently. And how inputs in IOS how to distinguish from string?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The way HTML elements are displayed by default depends on each Browser**, not necessarily on the device (Safari for iOS is not the same as Safari for OSX).

> In case you didn’t know, every browser has its own default ‘user
>   agent’ stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more
>   legible. For example, most browsers by default make links blue and
>   visited links purple, give tables a certain amount of border and
>   padding, apply variable font-sizes to H1, H2, H3 etc. and a certain
>   amount of padding to almost everything. Ever wondered why Submit
>   buttons look different in every browser?
>
> Obviously this creates a certain amount of headaches for CSS authors,
>   who can’t work out how to make their websites look the same in every
>   browser.
>
> Source: http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

It is common the use of [CSS Resets](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) to:

> ...force every browser to have all its styles reset to null, thus
>   avoiding cross-browser differences as much as possible.

This is meant about Browsers. Check for example [this article](https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/).

With regard of OS, each has different ways of styling its UI elements.

---

**Edit**:

If the question is also:

Why do inputs in touch devices tend to only have the [bottom border](http://www.tdl.com/~jrb/jrb7/css_textfield0.html) (line) ?

I would say it is a matter of style. But just as speculation, inputs and text-areas on desktop might need to have all borders to be distinguished from other elements. Desktop devices usually have bigger screens and more information displayed on them, whereas [touch](https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-labels) devices usually have smaller screens (so inputs might just need a minimum of a border-bottom). And after years this might have become the paradigm.

Comment: why elements looks different in different browser i understand. But I'm interested why IOS has made such a big difference with web elements. Here's how I see - first as you said, this is due to the format. Second string in front of you or INPUT depends on the context — you are in the "edit" mode or "view" mode

Comment: Maybe you can edit the question and be more specific, so others can help too.